# ADB TCP Connection Lost when Phone Unplugged

Tags: android, tcp, adb

I am following the google android developer guide on adb here: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless

After all the steps, I and I run `adb connect MY_IP`, it says that `connected to MY_IP:5555`.  However, when I unplug my phone from my computer, running `adb devices` shows that no devices are connected, and in Android Studio, it says no devices also.  How can I fix this?

I am using a macbook pro running Yosemite, and an HTC One m7 running android 4.4.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit:**
I just tested on an LG G3, and it worked. However, I need it to work on my HTC, because the LG isn't my phone. Why doesn't my HTC work?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?